# List of dates from DatetimeIndex object

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetimeindex

I have a `DatetimeIndex` object comprised of two dates given as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2014-1-1', '2014-1-2'], freq='D')
```

which looks like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

**How do I get a list of dates from the `timestamps` object?** i.e. I want the following:

```
['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
timestamps.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02']
```

Answer (score 6):

to_native_types() converts the values of timestamps to str format and then tolist() creates a list of str (dates).

```
timestamps.to_native_types().tolist()
```

Output

```
['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02']
```

Comment: Thanks for considering my comment. +1. Just add some explanatory words to your answer